# Iptables with Docker - All created networks accessible via lan, routing issue?

Tags: docker, networking

I would like to make the docker host a gateway to route all traffic on the 172.0.0.0 range, so all machines will be accessible via static routes on the local lan.

For example, take a look at the following table.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 bond0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-8cb984474cf3
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-08751d4f00ac
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-205529b1f9cc
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-f199a191f679
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-67ac401705aa
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-ec7ad4f839dd
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-f7af361c29fb
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

Bond0 is the LAN in question.

From the host we can ping each individual machine created by Docker because of the routing table.

1. Setup the static route on a windows box `route add 172.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 192.168.2.3`
2. Checked forwarding is enabled on the Linux Docker Host
3. Enabled Masquerading on the bond0 interface `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o bond0 -j MASQUERADE`
4. I chose an example interface `br-08751d4f00ac` that is 172.19.0.0
5. Setup forwarding

   `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o bond0 -j MASQUERADE
   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i bond0 -o br-08751d4f00ac -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br-08751d4f00ac -o bond0 -j ACCEPT`

However, I still can't ping from the windows machine on the same network as bond0.

```
Tracing route to 172.19.0.2 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.2.3
  2
```

Comment: This looks like a question more suited for [SF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was overthinking it!

I solved it with

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o bond0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i bond0 -o docker0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o bond0 -j ACCEPT
```

Solved the problem - I can now access all IP addresses allocated inside the docker containers from my LAN :)

Comment: Will this work between 2 AWS EC2 Instances? One having docker installed and running a container and the other being able to ping the docker container ip inside the docker0 network?